# how to configure an alert when a specific pod in k8s cluster goes into Failed state?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, kube-state-metrics

we are running spark on k8s cluster with help of [spark-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator). for monitoring we are using [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

we want to configure an alert so that whenever any pod related to spark jobs transition to **Failed** state we should get an alert. and this alert rule should check for such failed pods over last 5 minutes duration.

we tried to leverage the [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) for this but we are not able to get metrics on time based. at any given point of time metric **kube_pod_status_phase{namespace="spark-operator",phase="Failed"}** gives us the list of all the pods which are in failed state.

any suggestion or guidance on this are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum_over_time (kube_pod_status_phase{namespace="spark-operator",phase="Failed"}[5m:1m]) > 0
```